# bash script to remove prefix in file name

Tags: regex, bash

A bash script request(or fish script).
I have a bunch of files like:

```
SDF1211B-03 - name - lastname.info
SDF1213B-04 - names  - lastnames.info
SDF1211B-05 - name & name - lastname & lastname.info
```

but I want to change all of them to:

```
name - lastname.info
names  - lastnames.info
name & name - lastname & lastname.info
```

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: If you just need to rename files, why not use something like [filewrangler](http://development.christopherdrum.com/software/filewrangler/)?

Comment: Its a bash script. Im decent with bash except with sed awk and regex. Which half of bash so I guess I'm not that good.

Comment: You don't really need all that sed/awk/regex fancy schancy stuff in this case. :)

Comment: no money so no filewrangler or rename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
for x in SDF*.info; do
    mv "$x" "$(echo $x | cut -c14-)"
done
```

Comment: Be sure to quote `$x` inside the `$()` -- one of the file names has two spaces in it.

Comment: I thought it might need that, but I tried it as is and it works.

Comment: Yes, it probably works, but I bet it culls all multi-space regions down to one space.  Try it on a file named `SDF1234B-99 - begin        -        end.info` just to check.  (This form is HTML-izing my spaces.  There are 8 spaces before and after the second "-".)

Comment: Yes that is so. It will convert multi-space sequences to a single one. I wasn't sure if the OP's format counted on multispaces strictly or not.

Comment: I changed from -c15- to -c14-

Comment: Yeah sorry I miscounted. Good catch!

Comment: You could just use [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) instead of echo+cut, e.g. `mv "$x" "${x:14}"`

Answer (score 10):

I would do this with a for loop and the `${X#Y}` shell pattern:

```
for f in SDF?????-??' - '* ; do
    mv "$f" "${f#SDF?????-?? - }"
done
```

Comment: +1 No extra processes and POSIX-compatible as well.